# Efficiency of zkSNARKs as an Ethereum smart contract vs Zcash

Tags: fees, scalability, txpool, zksnark

How would the efficiency of zkSNARKs as an Ethereum smart contract compare to the same technology being used on its own blockchain (such as Zcash or Zclassic)?

By efficiency I mean 3 things:

1. Tranaction confirmation time
2. Transaction cost
3. Size of the transaction in kB

Answer (score 4):

Now we can compare, since a few days ago the Ropsten network just verified a Zcash transaction via a zkSNARK. Check it out [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x15e7f5ad316807ba16fe669a07137a5148973235738ac424d5b70f89ae7625e3).

1. Confirmation time: the same as for a usual Ethereum transaction.
2. The on chain verification transaction consumed 1933895 gas, which with a 21 Gwei gas price would approximately cost $10.722 on the mainnet.
3. cca. 0.7kB

To put things into perspective, let's have a look at Zcash shielded transactions:

1. Zcash block interval is 2.5mins and it takes around 5 block confirmations to fully settle a transaction.
2. Have a look at average Zcash [transaction costs](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/zcash-transactionfees.html). These days it's around $0.0005.
3. Anonymous Zcash transactions seem to be approximately 2 kB, according to Zcash engineer [Sean Bowe](https://github.com/ebfull).